# What is the best way to measure time in gem5 simulation environment

Tags: gem5

I am running a small matrix multiplication program in gem5 simulation environment and want to measure execution time of the program. The program is in Fortran and I use cpu_time before and after the matrix multiplication routine to get the time. But is there any other better way to measure time in the gem5 environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way of measuring stats for a given binary using gem5 in Full System mode is through providing an rcS script using the --script parameter:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.fast ... your_options... --script=./script.rcS
```

Your script should contain m5ops to reset and dump stats as required. An example script.rcS:

```
m5 resetstats
/bin/yourbinary
m5 dumpstats
```

Then from the stats.txt you can take execution time (sim_seconds) or whatever stat that you require. If you're using the Syscall Emulation mode you can directly check the stats.txt without the need for an rcS script.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Syscall Emulation mode. I will check out stats.txt and will let you know.

Comment: Got it. I will use sim_seconds now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add resetstats / dumpstats magic assembly instructions directly inside your benchmarks as shown at: [How to count the number of CPU clock cycles between the start and end of a benchmark in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944587/how-to-count-the-number-of-cpu-clock-cycles-between-the-start-and-end-of-a-bench/48944588#48944588) E.g. in aarch64:

```
/* resetstats */
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov x0, #0; mov x1, #0; .inst 0XFF000110 | (0x40 << 16);" : : : "x0", "x1")
/* dumpstats */
__asm__ __volatile__ ("mov x0, #0; mov x1, #0; .inst 0xFF000110 | (0x41 << 16);" : : : "x0", "x1")
```

You then likely want to look at the `system.cpu.numCycles` which shows how many CPU ticks passed.

Answer (score -1):

You can of course look into different stat files depending on your build but I think the easiest way is to flag time before your simulation command:

```
time ./build/ARM/gem5.fast ... your_options... --script=./script.rcS ...
```

Comment: This measures the time it takes for the simulator to run, not the time for the simulated binary...