# When to use full system FS vs syscall emulation SE with userland programs in gem5?

Tags: gem5

Since syscall emulation is much easier to setup, I'm wondering what are the advantages of using the full system emulation when running an userland program.

Or in other words, what interesting aspects are modeled in the full system but not syscall emulation mode, and when are they significant?

It is mentioned in the docs at: http://gem5.org/Splash_benchmarks that full system is

> Realistic: you're getting the actual Linux thread scheduler to schedule your threads

Is this the only advantage, or are there any other advantage for users that are optimizing their applications or investigating micro-architecture?

I also suspect that the MMU simulation is another important feature that is only modeled properly in full system mode, and could affect program performance.

Answer (score 3):

Advantages of SE:

- sometimes easier to setup benchmarks, [*if* all syscalls you need are implemented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961740/how-can-gem5-se-mode-execute-a-program-with-operating-system-dependencies/50962772#50962772) ([see also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51266763/9160762), [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50961740/how-can-gem5-se-mode-execute-a-program-with-operating-system-dependencies/50962772#50962772)), and *if* you have [just the right cross compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48959349/how-to-solve-fatal-kernel-too-old-when-running-gem5-in-syscall-emulation-se-m), which of course no one has documented properly which one that is.
- SE runs Dhrystone about 2x https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/00d282d912173b72c63c0a2cc893a97d45498da5#user-mode-vs-full-system-benchmark That benchmark makes no syscalls (except for information before / after the actual benchmark runs)
- it is easier to get greater visibility and control of what the application is doing since the kernel is not running in parallel. E.g. stats will be just for the application, GDB will be just for the application: [thread-aware gdb for the Linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561546/thread-aware-gdb-for-the-linux-kernel)

Disadvantages of SE:

- in practice, harder to setup benchmarks, because it is too fragile / has too many restrictions.

  If your content does not work immediately out of the box, it is easier to just create or download a full system image and go for that instead, which is much more reliable.

  Here is a sample minimal working Ubuntu setup if you are still interested: [How to compile and run an executable in gem5 syscall emulation mode with se.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53085048/how-to-compile-and-run-an-executable-in-gem5-syscall-emulation-mode-with-se-py/53085049#53085049)
- less representative, since no actual OS is running
- no dynamic linking for ARM as of June 2018: [How to run a dynamically linked executable syscall emulation mode se.py in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542222/how-to-run-a-dynamically-linked-executable-syscall-emulation-mode-se-py-in-gem5)
- if you want to evaluate an accelerator like a GPU, you will have to create some slightly custom interface for it, since there is no kernel driver running on top the the kernel as usual.

  Brandon has pointed out in his answer that this has in fact been done before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371006/9160762

So my recommendation is:

- try SE first. If it works, great. If it doesn't, try to fix it quickly, since most problems are trivial. Having the SE setup will save you a lot of time over full system, and it is often representative enough.
- otherwise, use FS mode. It is just simpler to setup, more representative, and the performance hit is acceptable for most.

  You could also use SE first, and then go to FS to further validate only your most important SE results, since FS is slower and you can therefore validate less different setups.

Answer (score 3):

Full system mode should be preferred (when it is possible to use it). There are benefits to using it, primarily fidelity in the simulation which is not possible with system call emulation mode. (The kernel interactions with an application can be important depending on the study that a researcher is trying to conduct.) Also, the user does not need to worry about implementing (or debugging) the system call implementation.

With that said, system call emulation mode can be useful under the right conditions. It is faster to run application code because there is no kernel running in the background. There is also no system noise if you want to mitigate it entirely. Arguably, it is easier to bootstrap a new device model as well. You can work on the model without driver support and make magic happen though fake interfaces. (It saves you having to model the bare-metal interface perfectly or having to write your own device driver.)

Your comments about dynamic linking and multi-threading support are related. If dynamic linking is fixed, you should be able to use your system's pthreads library and can forget about linking with m5threads entirely. The pthread library support has existed in the simulator for a while now (the system calls necessary for it to work properly).

However, there's a caveat to the threading implementation. You need to preallocate enough thread contexts at the start of simulation (by invoking with the -n option on the se.py script).

To elaborate, there is no operating system running in the background to schedule threads on the processors. (I use the terms threads and processors very loosely here.) To obviate the scheduling problem, you have to preallocate enough processors so that the threads can be created on calls to clone/execve. There is a constraint that you can never have more threads than processors (unlike a real system where the operating system can schedule them as it pleases).

The configuration scripts probably do not behave how a researcher would want them to behave for a multi-threaded workload. The researcher would need to verify that the caches were configured correctly and that they are sharing certain cache levels like a real machine would do. If the application calls clone/execve many times, it may not be possible to cause the generated configuration to behave realistically.

Your last statement about modeling accelerators is incorrect. The AMD GFX8 model does use system call emulation mode. (Also, we developed a NIC model which was never publicly released.) It involves creating a fake driver and manipulating it through the same ioctl interfaces that a real driver would use. Linux treats everything like a file so the driver is opened through the open system call interface and you can capture it there. There are other things which you might need to do (like map mmio ranges in the configuration), but the driver interface is the main piece. The application interacts with the driver and the driver interacts with the accelerator model.

Comment: Thanks for the info Brandon! I suspected there was a way to hack devices in syscall, but I thought it would be harder than it is! The AMD GFX8 model, is it in the mainline tree? If not, is there any other such example there?