# How to run an ARM multi-threaded program in Ruby system

Tags: c++, multithreading, arm, gem5

I fully implemented the content of the following webpage:
http://www.gem5.org/documentation/learning_gem5/part3/running/
The program can be compiled under X86 according to webpage requirements,however I want to get an ARM binary file,so I use the following code to compile it:

```
aarch64-linux-gnu-g++ -o threads threads.cpp -pthread -std = c ++ 11 -static
```

I can compile and get the binary file, but I get the following error during running:

```
erminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::system_error'

what():  Enable multithreading to use std::thread: Operation not permitted
```

Since the compiled ARM binary file is not provided in gem5's bin folder, does it mean that gem5 does not support running ARM multi-threaded programs, or my compilation options are wrong?

Comment: That can't be your actual command line, right? It should be `-std=c++11`, not `-std = c ++ 11`.

Answer (score 1):

That program fails to run with `-static` on both `qemu-aarch64` and Ubuntu 20.04 amd64 native (always check other more stable platforms :-))

It is known that there are some nongem5-specific problems with `-static` and threads, see e.g.: [when g++ static link pthread, cause Segmentation fault, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35116327/when-g-static-link-pthread-cause-segmentation-fault-why)

If workaround mentioned there don't work, you can now also run with dynamic linking as mentioned at: [How to run a dynamically linked executable syscall emulation mode se.py in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50542222/how-to-run-a-dynamically-linked-executable-syscall-emulation-mode-se-py-in-gem5/50696098#50696098) I've just tested it now and it worked with that example.

And at last note that there is a serious multithread SE Ruby problem which we are not sure how to solve: https://gem5.atlassian.net/browse/GEM5-676