# How to get stats for several gem5 full system userland benchmark programs under Linux without having to reboot multiple times?

Tags: gem5

I know how to modify my image, reboot, and re-run it, but that would make my experiments very slow, since boot takes a few minutes.

Is there a way to quickly switch:

- command line options
- the executable

that is being run after boot?

This is not trivial because the Linux kernel knows about:

- the state of the root filesystem
- the state of memory, and therefore of kernel CLI options that could be used to modify init

so I can't just switch those after a checkpoint.

This question is inspired from: https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg16959.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is [a fully automated setup that can help you to do it](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/d1f16390d0cd53a337e0014ce627803b1d6282de#gem5-run-benchmark).

The basic workflow is as follows:

- run your benchmark from the init executable that gets passed to the Linux kernel

  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122717/how-to-create-a-custom-linux-distro-that-runs-just-one-program-and-nothing-else/238579#238579
  - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/174062/can-the-init-process-be-a-shell-script-in-linux/395375#395375
- to run a single benchmark with different parameters without
  rebooting, do in your init script:

  ```
  m5 checkpoint
  m5 readfile | sh
  ```

  and set the contents of `m5 readfile` on a host filesystem file before restoring the checkpoint with:

  ```
  echo 'm5 resetstats && ./run-benchmark && m5 dumpstats' > path/to/script
  build/ARM/gem5.opt configs/example/fs.py --script path/to/script
  ```

  This is what the "configs/boot/hack_back_ckpt.rcS" but I think that
  script is overly complicated.
- to modify the executable without having to reboot, attach a second
  disk image and mount after the checkpoint is restored: 
  [How to attach multiple disk images in a simulation with gem5 fs.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862906/how-to-attach-multiple-disk-images-in-a-simulation-with-gem5-fs-py)

  Another possibility would be 9P but it is not working currently: http://gem5.org/WA-gem5
- to only count only benchmark instructions, do:

  ```
  m5 resetstats
  ./run-benchmark
  m5 dumpstats
  ```

  If that is not precise enough, modify the source of your benchmark with m5ops magic instructions that do resetstats and dumpstats from within the benchmark as shown at: [How to count the number of CPU clock cycles between the start and end of a benchmark in gem5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48944587/how-to-count-the-number-of-cpu-clock-cycles-between-the-start-and-end-of-a-bench/48944588#48944588)
- to make the first boot faster, you can boot with a simple CPU model like the default AtomicSimpleCPU and then switch to a more detailed, slower model after the checkpoint is restored: [How to switch CPU models in gem5 after restoring a checkpoint and then observe the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49011096/how-to-switch-cpu-models-in-gem5-after-restoring-a-checkpoint-and-then-observe-t)